# ssh: no route to host

Tags: wifi, ssh

I am trying to access Pi (ip: 192.168.11.20) using ssh via wifi (ap at 192.168.11.1) by another linux box (ip: 192.168.11.2). But it failed with the message:

`ssh: connect to host 192.168.11.20 port 22: No route to host`

It seems there is some problems on the route setup. Somehow the package can not be routed between Pi and linux box (as shown by the `nmap` output). Any comment is appreciated!

Here are the output of `route -n` on Pi (192.168.11.20)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Mestric Ref   Use  Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.11.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0       0     0    wlan0
0.0.0.0         192.168.11.1    0.0.0.0         UG    303     0     0    wlan0
192.168.11.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0       0     0    wlan0
192.168.11.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303     0     0    wlan0
```

and the `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:35:8b:e4
          inet6 addr: fe80::c39:5688:cd46:2d9f/64 Scope:Link  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:528 (528.0 B)  TX bytes:528 (528.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:5a:3a:62:73:e5
          inet addr:192.168.11.20  Bcast:192.168.11.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::326a:3aff:fe62:73e5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:45 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6766 (6.6 KiB)  TX bytes:15543 (15.1 KiB)
```

and finally the `nmap 192.168.11.*` (192.168.11.2 is missing)

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-16 23:33 CST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.11.1
Host is up (0.057s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain
80/tcp open  http

Nmap scan report for 192.168.11.20
Host is up (0.00047s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 5.03 seconds
```

On the other hand `route -n` from linux box (192.168.11.2)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.11.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.11.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

and `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:18:26:1c:85  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:d4700000-d4720000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:23143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3462530 (3.4 MB)  TX bytes:3462530 (3.4 MB) 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:27:10:01:eb:98  
          inet addr:192.168.11.2  Bcast:192.168.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::227:10ff:fe01:eb98/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:143189 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:124849 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:88955604 (88.9 MB)  TX bytes:20473398 (20.4 MB)
```

and finally `nmap 192.168.11.*` (192.168.11.20 is missing)

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-16 23:40 CST 
Nmap scan report for 192.168.11.1
Host is up (0.032s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain
80/tcp open  http

Nmap scan report for 192.168.11.2
Host is up (0.00028s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh 

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 14.59 seconds
```

**EDIT: Additional information on network setup**

This is the content of `/etc/network/interface` on Pi

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "my_wifi_id"
wpa-psk "my_passwd"
```

**Other information**

When I connect Pi to router directly via ethernet port, ssh from linux box to Pi works flawlessly. Also, I can connect to Pi via wifi from external network if I configure ip forwarding on the router to redirect incoming port (e.g. 2200) to port 22 at Pi's address (in this case 192.168.11.20).

Comment: Can you ping between the boxes? If you can't, that's the problem to sort out.

Comment: No, it failed with `Destination Host Unreachable`. But strangely, both ip can ping `8.8.8.8` and access internet normally.

Comment: What's between the two boxes?  Something between them doesn't know how to get from one to the other.

Comment: The connection is like this:
linux box <-> wifi ap <-> Pi.
Wifi ap is a simple Bufflo 150N router. 

I always access different machines within same subnet via ssh (even from android to laptop). I am quit certain the problem is in Pi's routing setup

Comment: I don't know why you have double entries on your Pi, but it looks suspicious. I'd also add `auto eth0` to your `/etc/network/interfaces` even though I doubt it will solve your issue. On my router I can isolate wifi from the rest of the network ... maybe that's the case with you too?

Comment: yeah... I agree that double entry looks suspicious. When I connect to Pi via eth0, there is only one entry with metric column 202..... I guess I have to remove the first wlan0 entry with metric 0. (I added `auto eth0` and it did not work)

Comment: I wonder what that metric column (value) means, as I have only seen it with a value of 0. And from that perspective, I'm more inclined to remove the entry with value 202 (unless you know what it means and deem it correct).

Comment: It seems like you're having some sort of firewall in your router, and one of the device(say Pi) is be placed in DMZ, and since one is outside router(DMZ) and one is inside router, router is preventing connections...

Answer (score 2):

If you are connected through wifi, it's possible that the router's wifi is configured for "CLIENT ISOLATION". This option allows all the clients of the wifi to access internet but doesn't allow interaction with other clients.

I think that this is why you can ping 8.8.8.8 but no other wifi client in the local network.

The solution is to disable the "client isolation" option in your wifi (wifi settings -> advanced settings) and then you will be able to connect to other clients.

PD: Of course, I supose that you have the SSH server enabled with raspi-config! :)

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr:

Give the PI a static IP address / make sure the Pi's MAC is only in the router's client list once.

---

This thread is really old, but I got this error today and thought I'd share my solution:

It seems the router got confused by a combination of 3 things:

1. Initial setup using ethernet cable
2. Configure WiFi while ethernet is still plugged in
3. Reboot the Pi without ethernet cable and change the hostname using raspi-config

This order seems to have confused my router, and I was unable to ping it or ssh into it using my pi-top or my Windows10 laptop.  My other Pi and my debian machine could ping it and ssh into it (but they're all hard-wired).

Looking in the router's client list, I could see that there were 2 clients with the same MAC address: a machine called raspberrypi and a machine called tinker-pi (the pi's new name).  I gave tinker-pi a static IP, and everything is fine now.

My guess is that the router did a MAC swap when I switched from eth0 to wlan0 using the same name, but opted to add a new client when I changed the name (because of the original MAC, maybe?).

Answer (score -2):

I had the following message:

> ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.99 port 22: No route to host

And it was because the ether-net cable was unplugged.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But if you look at the `ifconfig` printouts, you'll see that there seems to be a wlan connection at both points, and that they seem to be on the same subnet.